# PyMongo alternatives for Google App Engine

Tags: python, mongodb, google-app-engine

I had wrote a web site which accesses MongoDB Atlas using PyMongo, and now am trying to move it onto Google App Engine(GAE).

Since GAE allows only single-thread process and PyMongo is multi-threading implementation, I failed to move it naively.

Are there any good alternative packages of PyMongo, which should be a single-threading implementation?

Comment: I believe GAE Standard introduced support for multi-threading with Python 2.7 and you indicated it by using ```threadsafe: true``` in ```app.yaml``` file (see [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/legacy/standard/python/config/appref)). It's now default in Python 3 and so the attribute has been deprecated in Python 3 ```app.yaml``` file (see [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python3/migrate-to-python3/config-files#updating_appyaml))

Answer (score 0):

You can go for [Cloud FireStore](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/quickstart#python). It is a service by google and should integrate well with the Google App Engine. It has a python client API to help develop stuff in python.

Comment: Goyal san, thank you for your reply! Currently I have no thought to change the DB service. My question is about packages. If there are no packages to treat MongoDB Atlas in the single thread manner, I may have to think to change the service.

Comment: Oh, I got you now, sorry for my confusion.